# Unique ID and NAME of input text

Tags: php, increment

I output MySQL data to table. I need to set unique id and name of `<input>`. The current id is `brop`, but I want to add increment number (`brop1`, `brop2`, ...)

`<td><input type="text" id="brop" name="brop" value="'.$row["broj_operacije"].'"></td>`

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
$key = 1;
<td><input type="text" id="brop'. $key++ .' name="brop'. $key++ .'" value="'.$row["broj_operacije"].'"></td>
```

Comment: can you show the loop (`for` / `foreach`) too?

Comment: $key=1; should be declared outside the while /for loop

Comment: @FarazPV man, it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$key=1; should be declared outside the while /for loop

```
$key=1;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="brop'. $key++ .' name="brop'. $key++ .'" value="'.$row["broj_operacije"].'"></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the variable for row number outside the loop (`for` / `foreach`). You should also increment the row number once at the beginning of the loop body. In your case you increment the row number multiple times in one row:

```
$rowNumber = 0;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $rowNumber++;
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="brop'.$rowNumber.'" name="brop'.$rowNumber.'" value="'.$row["broj_operacije"].'"></td>';
}
```

---

Another solution using a `for` loop:

```
for ($rowNumber = 0; $rowNumber < count($rows); $rowNumber++) {
    $row = $rows[$rowNumber];
    echo '<td><input type="text" id="brop'.$rowNumber + 1.'" name="brop'.$rowNumber + 1.'" value="'.$row["broj_operacije"].'"></td>';
}
```

In this case you don't need an additional variable to hold the row number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $i=1;
   while($fetch_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
    {
       echo '<tr>
                <td>
                   <input type="text" id="brop'.$i.'" name="brop'.$i.'">
                </td>           
              </tr>';
         $i++;
    }
 ?>
```